# Java - How to make an ExecutorService running inside another ExecutorService not to shutdown when shutdown is invoked on the outer ExecutorService?

Tags: java, executorservice

I have a Executor service running inside another executor service to send emails. If I call shutdown on the outer executor, it is waiting for the inner executor service to shutdown which is drastically affecting the response time.

```
private final ExecutorService blastExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
private final ExecutorService mailExecutor  = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

public void findDealers() {

          blastExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                identifyDealers();
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                        }
                    });

        blastExecutor.shutdown();
        try {
            blastExecutor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        logger.info("Completed sending request blasts.");
}

public void identifyDealers() {

           mailExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                sendEmail();
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                        }
                    });
}
```

Here, at `blastExecutor.shutdown()` it invokes shutdown of `mailExecutor` as well(?)

This is just a sample code and there are lot of business happening inside `identifyDealers()` method. How can I make sendEmail asynchronous and make `blastExecutor.shutdown()` not to wait for shutdown of `mailExecutor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption seems to be wrong, `shutdown()` should only act on the outer executor. It does not shut down any other executors.

Here's a small example based on your code:

```
ExecutorService e1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
final ExecutorService e2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

e1.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("e1 started");

        e2.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("e2 started");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println("e2 completed");
            }
        });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

    }
});

e1.shutdown();
System.out.println("e1 shut down signal send");

e1.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
System.out.println("e1 terminated");

e2.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
System.out.println("e2 terminated");
```

The application won't terminate, it blocks on `e2.awaitTermination` and in the output it also shows that `e2` never got a shut down signal:

```
e1 started
e1 shut down signal send
e2 started
e1 terminated
e2 completed
```

If `mailExecutor` really does shut down, I think there is something else going on that is not shown in your code. As the basic structure of your code looks now, you are running a single task and immediately shut down the executer, which could mean you may don't even need the `blastExecutor`.

Comment: You are right. My assumption is wrong. It should be something else that is causing the delay. Thanks for your time!